# How play sound in silent mode with just audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

Is there any way to play the sound even in silent mode using this plugin?

If yes, send me a reference or what properties are needed?

I'm already using permissions of ACESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY and redirecting and activating my app user to allow managing the DND.